# I have two dates and need to find the difference in hours

Tags: linux, shell

Wed Jan 21 20:44:20 EST 2015
Wed Jan 21 19:04:20 EST 2015

I have two dates about, need to get the difference in minutes. Please help

"c=`date -d @$(( $(date -d "$b" +%s) - $(date -d "$a" +%s) )) -u +'%H:%M'`" -> This command is giving in HH:MM  but i want in MM

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gives you the result: `100` minutes:

```
echo $((($(date -d "$a" +%s) - $(date -d "$b" +%s))/60 ))
```

Note that, it will always give an int value, if you need the precision less than 1 min, like `100.25` you may want to use `bc` or `awk` to do the calculation instead of `$(( .. ))`